# Any way I could use a USB monitor with my Droid?

Tags: external-display, video-out, usb-peripherals

The Droid doesn't support video out but I'd like to have a bigger screen sometimes.  The [Mimo](http://www.mimomonitors.com/) would be cool but their they don't seem to have Android drivers (or even linux drivers).  Any way to do this?  *(Note: I do not want to have to run it through an existing computer)*

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the original Droid is completely hardware incapable of providing video out via usb. The Droid Incredible does provide this functionality, but it has a USB port specifically designed for it (extra pins).